# Why can't this enable_if function template be specialized in VS2017?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

The following compiled with VS2015, but fails in VS2017 with the below errors. Was the code doing something non standard that has been fixed in VS2017, or should VS2017 compile it?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <type_traits>

template <typename E>
constexpr auto ToUnderlying(E e)
{
    return static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<E>>(e);
}

template<typename T>
bool constexpr IsFlags(T) { return false; }

template<typename E>
std::enable_if_t<IsFlags(E{}), std::underlying_type_t<E>> operator | (E lhs, E rhs)
{
    return ToUnderlying(lhs) | ToUnderlying(rhs);
}

enum class PlantFlags { green = 1, edible = 2, aromatic = 4, frostTolerant = 8, thirsty = 16, growsInSand = 32 };

bool constexpr IsFlags(PlantFlags) { return true; }

int main()
{
    auto ored = PlantFlags::green | PlantFlags::frostTolerant;

    return 0;
}
```

Errors are:

```
c:\main.cpp(24): error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'enable_if<false,_Ty>::type
operator |(E,E)'
        with
        [
            _Ty=underlying_type<_Ty>::type
        ] 
c:\main.cpp(24): note: With the following template arguments:
c:\main.cpp(24): note: 'E=PlantFlags'
c:\main.cpp(24): error C2676: binary '|': 'PlantFlags' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
```

Comment: @Jarod42 ah, yes, thanks I'll get rid of that.

Comment: This [compiles on clang and gcc](https://godbolt.org/g/oKUxtQ)

Comment: Visual C++ is probably wrongly assuming `IsFlags(E{})` is always false. Edit: [seems not to be the way I expected](https://godbolt.org/g/sHS1Dh)

Comment: ideally VisualC++2017 is should be able to successfully compile the VisualC++2015 code since the 2017 is supposed be an in-place upgrade. This is interesting . .

Comment: raised with MS here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3141097

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is definitely a bug in Visual Studio. It [compiles on GCC and Clang](https://godbolt.org/g/oKUxtQ). It seems to be related with `constexpr` functions evaluated as template parameters. As a temporary workaround, you can make a template variable:

```
template <typename T>
bool constexpr is_flags_v = IsFlags(T{});

template<typename E>
std::enable_if_t<is_flags_v<E>, std::underlying_type_t<E>> operator | (E lhs, E rhs)
{
    return ToUnderlying(lhs) | ToUnderlying(rhs);
}
```

<sup>[On Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/iftYJD)</sup>

Comment: @ScottLangham It would be good to file a bug report with Visual Studio

Comment: Did you guys report the bug?

Comment: @ManjunathBabu I didn't report the bug; I haven't gotten around to it yet

Comment: I successfully compiled the program on VS2015, took the executable on another clean machine that has VS2017. The executable successfully ran without any errors on this new machine. Does this mean, VC++Redistributables support both versions?

Comment: @ManjunathBabu I would expect the executable to run just fine on another machine; this bug is a compile-time bug, not a runtime bug. I don't know much about VC++Redistributables

Comment: @ManjunathBabu Yeh, the platform toolset 140 used by VS2015 is binary compatible with the 141 used by VS2017. So, the same runtime can be used.

Comment: @Downvoter Where could I improve this answer? I would be happy to know what could be done better in this answer / future answer

Answer (score 4):

This might be a bug in Visual Studio. A possible workaround could be using template specialization instead of overloading:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_flags { constexpr static bool value = false; };

template <>
struct is_flags<PlantFlags> { constexpr static bool value = true; };

template<typename E> std::enable_if_t<is_flags<E>::value, std::underlying_type_t<E >> operator | (E lhs, E rhs)
{
    return ToUnderlying(lhs) | ToUnderlying(rhs);
}
```

Comment: on which version of Visual Studio was this code run?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The intention of the original code is to allow  selected enums to work with bitwise operators and not others. I'm not sure this workaround can achieve that.

Comment: I used Microsoft Optimized C++ Compiler Version 19.11.25507.1, included in VS 2017.3.

Comment: I adjusted the workaround. Maybe a bit bulky, but does the job.

Comment: Possibly! Sorry for moving the goal... but the code-base has the operator and non-specialized is_flags in a Library namespace. When defining an enum in a different namespace, it would be necessary to exit the namespace and open the Library namespace before specializing the is_flags and then get back to the original namespace. I guess that's possible, but is a bit of a pain for a library that's supposed to make working with enum as flags a breeze.