# enable_if not working in Visual Studio when using a constexpr function as argument

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++14, constexpr, enable-if

I'm currently wrestling with Visual Studio 2017 (compiling using `/std:c++latest` if that's any help).

The code in question simply selects a struct specialization based on the result of some templated `constexpr` function. GCC and clang have no trouble compiling it.

Here's my MCVE:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct A {
  enum {
    test_trait = true
   };
};

template<typename T>
constexpr int choose() {
  return T::test_trait;
}

template<typename T, typename Enable=void>
struct Chosen;

template<typename T>
struct Chosen<T, std::enable_if_t<choose<T>() == 1>> {};

void foo() {
  // This works
  constexpr int chosen = choose<A>();
  static_assert(chosen == 1, "");

  // This resolves to the undefined struct.
  using Chosen_t = Chosen<A>;
  Chosen_t x;
  (void)x;
}
```

`choose()` is actually a fair bit more complex in my codebase, but the `static_assert` still compiles, and checks fine.

I kinda assumed that if the `static_assert` compiles, there is no reason for the `enable_if` to not be able to do its magic. Am I wrong? I guess "maybe" `T` is not technically a dependant type of the `enable_if`... But if that was the case, I'd expect GCC and clang to slap my wrist.

I can get around this by wrapping the result of `choose()` in a `std::integral_constant`, like so:

```
template<typename T> 
struct Chooser : public std::integral_constant<int, choose<T>()> {};

template<typename T>
struct Chosen<T, std::enable_if_t<Chooser<T>::value>> {};
```

But I'd really rather not have to jump through that hoop.

Should template resolution be able to resolve this the way I expect? I'm worried that the code is actually wrong, and GCC and clang are just being lenient on me.

Comment: Does this work on VS 2015? It's possible this is a bug related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46104002/1896169)

Comment: @Justin Just checked: Nope visual studio 2015 seems to have the same error.

Comment: VC++ is just hideously broken when it comes to templates. The code is completely fine. Employ your workaround and call it a day?

Comment: @Columbo, I wouldn't call my code "fine" if it can't be used in a portable way :(. But yeah, I guess this will have to do, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Code still appears to be broken in MSVC 19.00.23506. However, it appears to work with just one more level of indirection (perhaps a better workaround):

```
template<typename T, bool>
struct ChosenImpl;

template<typename T>
struct ChosenImpl<T, true> {};

template<typename T>
using Chosen = ChosenImpl<T, choose<T>()>;
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/STWL10597)

A benefit to this is that we are hiding the second template argument from the caller, which they don't care about anyway.