# How to make .lib file for visual studio using mingw and Cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to build my cpp library by using Mingw and Cmake in windows and using it in Visual studio as static or shared library.

As you already know, Mingw gives us `.a` file format as a static library file, whereas Visual Studio uses `.lib` as a library file format.

So, I tried to convert `.a` file to `.lib` file by using CMake option `CMAKE_GNUtoMS`

Here is my CMakeList file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
find_program(CMAKE_GNUtoMS_VCVARS
        NAMES vcvars64.bat
        PATHS "MSVC"
        )
set(CMAKE_GNUtoMS ON)

project (test_project)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_library(test_project  SHARED library.cpp)
```

Visual Studio is not installed on my computer, so I imported `vcvars64.bat` from another computer that has Visual Studio installed and put it in my workspace.

Here is the folder tree of my project

```
C:.
|   CMakeLists.txt
|   library.cpp
|   library.h
|
\---MSVC
        vcvars32.bat
        vcvars64.bat
        vcvarsall.bat
        vcvarsamd64_x86.bat
        vcvarsx86_amd64.bat
```

I tried to build with these folder tree and CMakeLists file, `.dll` and `.a` files were created from mingw, and even `.def` files were created **but**  it could not be converted to `.lib` files with with the error message below.

```
FAILED: libtest_project.dll libtest_project.dll.a 
cmd.exe /C "cd . && "C:\PROGRA~1\JetBrains\CLion 2021.3.3\bin\mingw\bin\g++.exe" -g   -shared -o libtest_project.dll -Wl,--out-implib,libtest_project.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 CMakeFiles/test_project.dir/library.cpp.obj  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 -Wl,--output-def,test_project.def && "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2021.3.3\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" -Dlib="C:/Users/998ju/CLionProjects/test_project/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeGNUtoMS_lib.bat" -Ddef=test_project.def -Ddll=libtest_project.dll -Dimp=libtest_project.dll.a -P "C:/Program Files/JetBrains/CLion 2021.3.3/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/Platform/GNUtoMS_lib.cmake" && cd ."
The specified configuration type is missing.  The tools for the
configuration might not be installed.
'lib'��(�뒗) �궡遺� �삉�뒗 �쇅遺� 紐낅졊, �떎�뻾�븷 �닔 �엳�뒗 �봽濡쒓렇�옩, �삉�뒗
諛곗튂 �뙆�씪�씠 �븘�떃�땲�떎.
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/JetBrains/CLion 2021.3.3/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/Platform/GNUtoMS_lib.cmake:9 (message):
  lib failed: 1
```

I have no idea what the error message that comes out with unknown characters. So it's hard to debugging the problems

So, if you have any hints, please let me know.
Best regards

Comment: I have to build with GCC because MSVC is not fully supporting c++14 [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46144103/enable-if-not-working-in-visual-studio-when-using-a-constexpr-function-as-argume)

Comment: C++ libraries built with MinGW are incompatible with MSVC, and vice versa. You'll have to fix your code.

Comment: You can't just copy the batch files off another machine, they need registry entries and those entries in turn point to build tools. Why not just install the visual studio build tools?